# MVC Razor Tree Structured List based on Model with Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, recursion, tree, recursive-datastructures

I have a qustion on how to use recursion in MVC Razor to generate a tree-structured list based on a model with a PersonID, FatherID and MotherID.

Here is my model:

```
public partial class ResultSet
{
    public Nullable<decimal> PersonID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> FatherID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MotherID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Level { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The Level indicates how deep into the tree the person is. 
Here is an example of a `ResultSet` recordset from my SQL Stored Procedure:

```
PersonID  FatherID  MotherID  Level  Gender
119       120       NULL      0      M
120       121       122      -1      M
121       123       124      -2      M
122       125       126      -2      V
123       NULL      NULL     -3      M
124       NULL      NULL     -3      V
125       127       128      -3      M
126       NULL      NULL     -3      V
127       NULL      NULL     -4      M
128       NULL      NULL     -4      V
```

I have loaded this resultset into an instance of List, which i am accessing in my view. My view looks like this right now:

```
@model AbInitio.Models.Person
@using AbInitio.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stamboom van: " + Model.FirstName + " " + Model.LastName;
}

<h2>Stamboom van @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</h2>

@{
List<ResultSet> family = (List<ResultSet>)ViewData["family"];

int counterLimit = ViewBag.levelCount;
int counterStart = 0;
int[] levels= ViewBag.levels;

@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<ResultSet> family , int[] levels, int counterStart, int counterLimit)
{
    if (counterStart < counterLimit) {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var p in family.Where(s => s.Level.Equals(levels[counterStart])))
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">@p.PERSOONSNUMMER</a>
                    @ShowTree(familie, levels, counterStart + 1, counterLimit)

                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
}

<div class="tree">
    @ShowTree(familie, levels, counterStart, counterLimit)
</div>
```

My CSS handles the ul and li tags and transforms it into a tree structure as shown here: [CSS Tree Structure Example](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree).
Basically, I am stuck on the helper class that uses recursion to generate the correct list. I need the Persons with the lowest "Level" value on the first level of the tree structure. In this case that would be the persons with PersonID 127 & 128. Then on the next level their childs should be Persons 123-126 etc..

Any solutions for the helper class would be appreciated greatly!